# Terraform - validate a variable based on another variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Say I have a Terraform module for creating a AWS EC2 instance.

Now, I want the user to be able to either use the default VPC, or provide another VPC ID.
So I define the following input variables:

```
# variables.tf

variable "default_vpc" {
  description = "Whether or not deploy the instance in the default VPC"
  type = bool
}

variable "vpc_id" {
  description = "VPC ID to deploy the instance in"
  type = string
  default = ""
}
```

Now, in case the user passes `false` for `default_vpc`, I want to ensure that he does pass some value in `vpc_id`. Is that possible?

Comment: Not the way you currently want to do it.

Comment: You would need to combine these variable declarations somehow.

Answer (score 0):

While there's no way to implement using [input variable validation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/custom-conditions#input-variable-validation), depending on the Terraform version you can use [preconditions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/custom-conditions#preconditions-and-postconditions).

```
resource "null_resource" "vpc_precondition_validation" {
  lifecycle {
    precondition {
      condition     = (var.default_vpc == false && var.vpc_id != "") || (var.default_vpc == true && var.vpc_id == "")
      error_message = "There has been error while validating the inputs for default_vpc and vpc_id variables."
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, when we input `false` for the variable `default_vpc` and we don't provide a value for the `vpc_id` variable it's going to print the error message.

When `default_vpc` is set to true, it will allow the `vpc_id` variable to be an empty string.

Then in the resource where the `vpc_id` is required, you can use a ternary condition, assuming the default vpc id attribute is retrieved from a data source:

```
...
vpc_id = var.default_vpc == false ? var.vpc_id : data.aws_vpc.default.id
...
```

Answer (score -1):

**You could be declaring it as a boolean map like this:**

```
variable "vpc_id" {
  type = map(bool)
  default = {
    true    = "default_vpc is true"
    false   = "default_vpc is false"
  }
}
```

**Now you could be using it like this:**

```
var.vpc_id[${var.default_vpc}]
```

**Example:**

[image: Example]

Comment: How does this satisfy OP requirements?

Comment: @javierlga sry could you rephrase

Comment: I don't understand how your suggestion about using a map will help what OP is asking about validating a Terraform variable based on the input provided by another variable.

Comment: well the question is

> in case the user passes false for default_vpc, I want to ensure that he does pass some value in vpc_id

if default_vpc is false, then var.vpc_id[${var.default_vpc}] is var.vpc_id[false] is the inilialization value "default_vpc is false" by default

Comment: How would he then consume the `vpc_id` if it's a map of boolean values? He's asking about using input variable validation https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/custom-conditions#input-variable-validation, unfortunately, Terraform doesn't allow to validate a variable input using other variable input but only referring to the variable itself.

Comment: Ok I get you. I'll extend with an example: making default_vpc default to false, and initialising  vpc_id[false], results in "user passes false for default_vpc". See example screenshot.

Comment: But how does that help? That’s not useful, all it prints it’s a message, it’s not actually validating anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251277/discussion-between-javierlga-and-mel-te).